# How to give a bookmark for a text in PDF IText 5?

Tags: pdf, itext

I know it may sound simple...but I have been searching for the code for adding bookmark, when the bookmark is clicked should go to the text content which is there in PDF.

Lets say I have bookmark GO TO XYZ and in the PDF I have added doc.add(new Phrase("Should Point Me"))

Here is my code

```
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
PdfOutline gotoXyz= new PdfOutline(root,
                    new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH, writer.getVerticalPosition(true)), "GO TO XYZ", true);
```

I found in Itext 7 we give ExplicitDestination with pageNumber...neither I can use Itext7 or use pageNumber I need to point to text content in PDF using bookmark...

Please help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1**

You have:

```
doc.add(new Phrase("Should Point Me"));
```

Replace this with:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is the ");
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("destination");
chunk.setLocalDestination("XYZ");
p.add(chunk);
doc.add(p);
```

You have now create a local destination with name `XYZ`. This is similar to having `<a name="XYZ">` in HTML.

**PART 2**

You now need something like `<a href="#XYZ">`. That would be an action:

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("XYZ", false);
```

You can use this action from your content like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Go to ");
Chunk destination = new Chunk("destination");
destination.setAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("XYZ", false));
p.add(destination);
document.add(p);
```

You can also use this action in the context of a `PdfOutline`.

You have:

```
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
PdfOutline gotoXyz= new PdfOutline(root,
    new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH, writer.getVerticalPosition(true)), "GO TO XYZ", true);
```

And that might work approximately, but this should also work:

```
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
PdfOutline gotoXyz= new PdfOutline(root,
    new PdfDestination("XYZ"), "GO TO XYZ");
```

You probably could even use this:

```
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
PdfOutline gotoXyz= new PdfOutline(root,
    PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("XYZ", false), "GO TO XYZ");
```

Comment: `Paragraph p = new Phrase("This is the ");` - this looks wrong.